# THREE.FirstPersonControls is not a constructor

Tags: three.js

I am started developed recently and i now i am having some problems. A have error **THREE.FirstPersonControls is not a constructor**, but i connected the FirstPersonControls.js to my project :/

I tried connect it by link to file three/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js, but it ended up the same way :/

FirstPersonControls.js file i have in my project, i rechecked.

```
<meta charset=utf-8>

<title>what</title>
<style>

    body { margin: 0; }
    canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
</style>
```

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="module">

import * as THREE from './three/build/three.module.js';
import {FirstPersonControls} from './three/examples/jsm/controls/FirstPersonControls.js';

const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 2, 0.1, 5);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

var k = 3;

controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera );

controls.movementSpeed = 70;
controls.lookSpeed = 0.05;
controls.noFly = true;
controls.lookVertical = false;

camera.position.z = k;

var boxWidth = 2;

var boxHeight = 1;

var boxDepth = 2;

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x44aa88});

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

const geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x44aa88});

var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

cube.rotation.y = 0.4;
cube.rotation.x = 0.3;
cube.position.x = 1;
cube2.rotation.y = 0.4;
cube2.rotation.x = 0.3;
cube2.position.x = -1;
cube2.position.y = 0;
cube2.position.z = +1;

scene.add(cube);
scene.add(cube2);

renderer.render(scene, camera);

function render(time) {

    time = 1000;

    k -= 0.1;

    cube.rotation.x = k;
    cube.rotation.y = k;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    controls.update();

}

render();

</script>
```

Comment: Try it this way: `new FirstPersonControls( camera , renderer );`.

Comment: thank you, but now got a error - this.domElement.setAttribute is not a function
    at new FirstPersonControls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of creating an instance of `FirstPersonControls` with modules is:

```
controls = new FirstPersonControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

`three.js R115`